# When using angular with scss, how can I see the translated css?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, kendo-ui-angular2

When using scss in an angluar cli app, where I can i see the resulting css that was generated and ng build was complete?

relevant section from angular.json

```
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/ClientApp",
    "index": "src/index.html",
    "main": "src/main.ts",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
    "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
      "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
      "src/styles.scss"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ]
```

and

```
  "defaultProject": "ClientApp",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
```

Comment: Why is this post tagged as Kendo? Angular build everything into a dist folder. Heve a look there, and also here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/build.md

Comment: because im using a custom bootstrap theme from kendo and using scss variables to override.

Comment: you can make a custom css file with the dict !important; when you need to override the prop. Anyway everything is in the dist folder, as I said before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
ng build
```

Which will put your transpiled files into `dist/`, then check that folder for your `css` files.

Relevant docs: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#creating-a-build

Comment: No css, but rather styles.js which looks like it has all the bootstrap and fontawesome style info im refrencing.  However, I see nothing from my scss file

Comment: Ok, I will use the --extract-css option and see if my content is there

Comment: using the ng build option (--extract-css) helped me find what I was looking for, it was working as expected, i just wasnt seeing it.