# Generating CSS from Angular SCSS?

Tags: css, angular, sass

Is there a way to see the CSS that corresponds to the SCSS when we are using SCSS as the preprocessor for Angular?

There is an answer here:
[When using angular with scss, how can I see the translated css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215602/when-using-angular-with-scss-how-can-i-see-the-translated-css)

And it mentions using the `--extract-css` option, however when I try that it looks like it has been deprecated:

```
sandbox/project $ ng build --extract-css
Unknown option: '--extract-css'
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why do you need to see the translated `css`?

Comment: I'm going through the Angular Material source code and trying to understand it and it would be a lot easier if I could import snippets and generate the corresponding CSS ...

Comment: maybe converter will help you here https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css

Comment: It has to be in an Angular CLI environment, because it allows me to see various imports from Angular Material ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Styles in Angular Build Files

In your build files the styles of components will actually be compiled in the `main.js` file. You can find it in the network tab of your browsers developertools.

You will also see a file called `styles.css`, but this will only contain your global styles. This is because of Angulars view-encapsulation of styles per component. The behavior of angular may change if you change the view-encapsulation strategy as explained [here](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation) to:

- Emulated (default)
- ShadowDOM
- None

*I would not recommend doing that though.*

However, if you want you can compile your sass files into css using the command line tool you can install as explained on the [official sass website](https://sass-lang.com/install).

You can also just use online sass converters like [thisone](https://jsonformatter.org/sass-to-css).

If you are just interested in the global styles here's a reference to [How you can switch the format from scss to css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72446771/telling-angular-to-serve-styles-css-instead-of-styles-scss) in your browser.

#### Example

app.component.scss

```css
p {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

styles.scss

```css
@import 'default';

p {
   color: red;

   &:hover {
      color: blue;
   }
}
```

default.scss

```css
h1 {
  color: teal;
}
```

#### Result in Build

styles.css:

```css
h1 {
  color: teal;
}

p {
  color: red;
}

p:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

main.js:

```js
AppComponent.ɵfac = function AppComponent_Factory(t) { return new (t || AppComponent)(); };
AppComponent.ɵcmp = /*@__PURE__*/ _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["ɵɵdefineComponent"]({ type: AppComponent, selectors: [["app-root"]], decls: 1, vars: 0, template: function AppComponent_Template(rf, ctx) { if (rf & 1) {
        _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["ɵɵelement"](0, "lib-my-lib");
    } }, directives: [my_lib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.MyLibComponent], styles: ["p[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n  background-color: orange;\n}\n/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbImFwcC5jb21wb25lbnQuc2NzcyIsIi4uXFwuLlxcLi5cXC4uXFxBbmd1bGFyJTIwUHJvamVjdHNcXGxpYi1leGFtcGxlXFxzcmNcXGFwcFxcYXBwLmNvbXBvbmVudC5zY3NzIl0sIm5hbWVzIjpbXSwibWFwcGluZ3MiOiJBQUFBO0VBQ0Usd0JBQUE7QUNDRiIsImZpbGUiOiJhcHAuY29tcG9uZW50LnNjc3MiLCJzb3VyY2VzQ29udGVudCI6WyJwIHtcclxuICBiYWNrZ3JvdW5kLWNvbG9yOiBvcmFuZ2U7XHJcbn1cclxuIiwicCB7XG4gIGJhY2tncm91bmQtY29sb3I6IG9yYW5nZTtcbn0iXX0= */"] });
```

**Note the orange background-color in the last line.*

Comment: HI.  I tried the suggestion, but unfortunately I don't see any CSS in the main.js file.  Also tried the SASS tooling, but it gets confused when using certain angular imports.  I think Angular has develop additional import capabilities ...

Comment: The css will not look like regular css but js. Try looking for some keywords of your css in the `main.js` file. You will not be able to make too much sense out of it though. The imports are native to sass and the command line tool should recognize and even fetch them. (It might not be able to for some reason. I don't know what you're trying to import and where from.) Try commenting the imports that don't work, and create a dummy second sass and import that, then use the tool and you'll see. I'm not sure about online sources or anything, but it works fine for me on my own files.

Comment: As an experiment I tried putting some SASS in `styles.scss` and running the app.  The styles show up in the Chrome Developer tools ... however `main.js` is still empty ...

Comment: `styles.scss` is the global styling that you can find styles.css in the build files, yes. It is only component styles that you will find in `main.js`. Apart from setting defaults for the whole app and importing some third party starting points, I wouldn't try styling your whole app in there. That way you would lose the view-encapsulation.

Comment: I also tried putting SCSS code in app.component.scss and looking for the corresponding CSS in main.js, but it is not there.  The main use case I have is experimenting with SCSS to find out what the corresponding CSS will be.  Angular Material features some fairly advanced use cases and I'm trying to understand how they are structuring their SCSS.  So being able to `@use` their snippets in `styles.scss` and generating the corresponding CSS is mainly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I've created this web container on Stacblitz to play around with various scenarios.  It does compile SASS at least, so it's a start :).  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9tzuk-2ji12p?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Comment: Hmmm ... OK I was playing around with this a little more and when I click on the element demo button using Chrome Developer Tools the styles tab does have the generated `styles.css` in it ...which is pretty sweet, because that's exactly what I was looking for.  I think this may be a web container only feature, because when I was doing the same thing with the CLI it showed me the `styles.scss` file ... perhaps you could integrate this into the answer and then I can accept it.

Comment: That's what I said, I added a very simple example to my answer showing exactly what I was trying to explain. I hope it helps. I am using Angular 13, I'm not entirely sure if that matters a lot. I don't think so, unless you go back a lot of versions.

Comment: Well it does look like there is something generated into `main.js` ... but it's Javascript that I assume gets compiled into the rendering of the component when the component is using style encapsulation and that also makes it much harder to read and interpret.  The web container Stackblitz demo I linked does generate `styles.css` and I think a lot of people will find this helpful.

Comment: This is a related question that I just created.  This is mainly what I'm looking for and I think this is also the main use case for many.  If we can figure out how to do this, then we will be able to experiment and see what CSS is being generated.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72446771/telling-angular-to-serve-styles-css-instead-of-styles-scss

Comment: I don't understand, it always serves the global styling in styles.css ... But it does not contain the component styling. Not even in your example. The example in my answer was locally served with CLI. Your browser can't read scss.... It is always transpiled.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but if you look at the link to the other stackoverflow question I included a screenshot of what is served in the browser when attempting to see `styles.css`.  Instead of serving `styles.css` it serves `styles.scss`.

Comment: I wrote up a quick article.  You can see in the screenshot I included that the Angular CLI project serves `styles.scss` when viewing styles in the Chrome Developer Tooling.  https://fireflysemantics.medium.com/viewing-generated-global-css-for-angular-sass-projects-857a6887ff0b

Comment: You can just select the format you want for the global styles in your chrome devtools. I answered your other question too.

Comment: If you could provide screenshots that would be really great ...

Comment: Might be nice to reference the other question here as I found that elaboration super helpful.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72446771/telling-angular-to-serve-styles-css-instead-of-styles-scss

Comment: I added it to the answer as well so it isn't buried in these comments.

Comment: I just realized something really "Stoooooopid".  The `styles.css` tab is right next to `styles.scss` ... and so we don't actually have to disable the source maps for CSS ...

Comment: I put a screenshot of it is this article ... https://fireflysemantics.medium.com/viewing-generated-global-css-for-angular-sass-projects-857a6887ff0b

Answer (score -1):

This is just a complement to the accepted answer. I wrote it up in a medium article, as it was not immediately obvious as `styles.scss` is opened first when selecting elements in Chrome Developer Tooling, but `styles.css` is in the tab right next to it.

https://fireflysemantics.medium.com/viewing-generated-global-css-for-angular-sass-projects-857a6887ff0b