# Telling Angular to serve `styles.css` instead of `styles.scss`

Tags: css, angular, sass

In this [web container stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9tzuk-2ji12p?file=src%2Fstyles.scss) if we click on the rendered button element in Chrome Developer tooling we can see the generated `styles.css`.

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

When I try to do the same thing in an Angular CLI project, Angular will serve the `styles.scss` file, instead of `styles.css`.

This is a screenshot.

[image]

Is there a way to tell Angular to serve `styles.css` instead of `styles.scss` when working with local CLI based projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edge

When you open up styles.scss by clicking on it in the styles tab of your devtools in **Edge**, you can just select the format you want in the tabs above the stylesheet it presents to you. I you can't see it you can click the `>>` arrows to show the option in a dropdown.

However, **you will only see the global styles there**. *Not the component styling.*

Click on the styles.scss on the right:

[image]

Select whatever presentation you prefer in the tabs:

[image]

### Chrome

Go to devtools settings and disable CSS sourcemaps. (Second column, next to last check mark.)

[image]

Now you will see styles.css only in the right of your styles tab.

[image]

Comment: If you could screen shot the process that would be awesome.  Unfortunately I don't see the >> dropdown option ...

Comment: I added pictures for you on how to switch between scss and css in both Edge and Chrome. I like how Edge handles this more. I would think this is similar to how it works on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

1. When you generate the project; you can tell it to use CSS instead of SCSS.  There is probably a way to switch a project from SCSS to CSS within the Angular.json.
2. If you create and deploy a production build; it should not include source maps; and therefore you'll probably see CSS files in developer tools.

Comment: My use case is to be able to experiment with more advanced SASS techniques.  I'm also going through the Angular Material SASS Source so I was looking for a way to see what CSS is generated from the SASS.  I was hoping, like you say, that there is a way to switch this on in angular.json, so that it allows for a more streamlined development experience ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to serve different stylesheets depending on the configuration you run.

You can configure which global stylesheets to include in your Angular build via the `angular.json` config file:

https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-and-scripts-configuration

You can achieve this by creating a configuration for running your project locally and swap the .scss file for the .css file there.